# Strange notation in a Chopin waltz

Tags: piano, notation, technique

I have two questions regarding Chopin's Waltz in E minor.

1. On the picture there are two A notes. How does one play the A's? (The rythm  is 3/4  ). For me this does not make any sense?

[image]

2. In the piece are staccato notes combined with pedals. How are they played? Because the staccato automatically vanishs if I press the sustain pedal.

Comment: I suggest to split this to two questions. First one is easy (and surely a duplicate of an existing one, liable to close votes): The half note is intended as separate voice lasting during the following two eights and the quarter of the second voice.

Comment: You can find an answer for the second part of your question [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/4051/34776).

Comment: First part is answered [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/61200/2600), so in total both parts are duplicate and I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two simultaneous voices.  The execution basically is that you play the attack (key down) of the A to fit with the beamed eighth phrase but you release that key only together with the quarter note C.

This sort of multivoice notation that requires making some judicious choices for approximating on the piano (which has only a single manual) is not exactly rare.