# Second note is not played

Tags: sheet-music

[image]

I don't see any tie symbol of these two notes A (La), but these two notes are played at once.
Please explain to me why
Thanks

Comment: This post gives a better answer regarding execution: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/63864/70803

Comment: Also this post: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/99352/70803.

Comment: Thanks, it's a duplicate, but without good level of vocabulary it's hard to find the anwser!

Comment: Notice, something similar is happening in the top stave.