# What does this number 3 next to the note mean?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

This is a picture from my sheet for Chopin's Nocturne in F minor, Op. 55, No. 1. I don't understand what the number next to this note means.

[image: Sheet music with 3 next to note]

Comment: And - how to play a staccato note *and* pedal it?

Comment: Hi,   please post the edition you are working with.  That is very helpful to people trying to answer.

Comment: @Tim  Not a pianist but my recall is the staccato indicates how to strike the note, i.e. hit and release the key fast, which produces slightly different overtone than whacking the hammer down as though you were holding the key down, pedal or not.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I've often wondered about staccato with pedal - a whole grade V piece in ABRSM had those markings, and no-one from there could tell me exactly what the student should do. I'll try your idea later.

Comment: @Tim   maybe this   https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4048/on-the-piano-how-should-you-play-staccato-with-the-pedal

Comment: It may (or may not, I'm not too familiar with Chopin's works) help to note that while contemporary interpretation of the staccato marking holds it to mean a cut off note or to play "disconnected," the mark traditionally means to play half the notated value. (eg, a staccato quarter not would be played as an eight) In this interpretation there would be no complications in playing staccato with a pedal.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a fingering. It shows you that you need to play C with the 3rd finger and thus Ab* with the 1st one. You'd also play the low F with your pinky (5th finger).

It's quite common to include the fingerings in pieces; it's a way to help the player. Usually, you'd find the numbers on top of the note.From the link I'm providing below, you can see that:

[image]

The author here mentions fingerings in different parts and above the notes, but the logic of it is the same. Also, from this extract of the piece you can see that there is nothing fishy going on before or after the part you asked about (5th bar in my pic) and that it's simply a fingering.

<sub>* I'm saying Ab, because the [piece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3yrEEM5j_s) is in F minor</sub>

Comment: This is most likely right, but it's odd to have finger numbers in a space. Usually, as in your example, on top or underneath. And surely a player could work that fingering out for himself?!

Comment: @Tim true, as I mentioned in my second paragraph. It doesn't seem to be like something else, since it makes sense to finger it like that. My guess is that this was from a poorly written/edited edition

Comment: @Tim I'm saying it's a fingering, too, despite its unusual location, because 1) It isn't anything else that makes sense, 2) it's the finger I would use for that note, and 3) there isn't a lot of room below the note because of the pedal marking. As for working the fingering out for oneself, I'm reminded of George Carlin's maxim that every driver is either crazy or an idiot, depending on whether he's driving faster or slower than you are. Fingerings are either obvious or something nobody in his right mind would use! I find examples of both in the above passage.

Comment: @BobRodes - I agree that it's most likely a fingering number. It's just odd to put it in the space, when there's room for it in the *normal* place. Had it been on a line, it would look even odder. Fingerings - well, there's often few options, and in any case, with different physiology, one person's fingering is another's nghtmare! I like the driving analogy. True, when I'm on the road, there are few normal drivers ever to be seen...

Comment: @Tim, it is a bit odd, indeed. My speculation is that there really isn't room to put it in the normal place, because with the pedal release marking there it would get a bit crowded.

Comment: @BobRodes - just played it, and it's the most obvious finger to use! So why bother at all putting '3', especially as there's little room. I say it's pointless! (And confusing - ask OP).

Comment: @Tim I agree; see my point 2) above. And again, fingerings are either idiotically obvious or crazy. There are few that aren't one or the other. :) Seriously, though, at an early point in my development, I probably would have tried using 4 there (since I generally used 14 or 25 for sixths), and would have had more trouble hitting the bass notes than if I had used 3. So to student drivers old people are idiots and everyone else is crazy! (Can't help it, sorry.)